# Exponential Modelling; growth rate percentage to find length of cylindrical snake in regards to level number of snake game?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, problem-solving, volume, mathematical-modeling

The problem I have is;

An app developer is creating a 3D snake game using a cylindrical model. Each time the snake grows, which occurs after it eats enough mice to level up and have a growth spurt, it will increase in volume by a certain constant percentage, and in such a manner that the ratio of its length to its cross sectional area remains constant. Ie - L/A= constant (k)

I need help in determining a mathematical model for the length of the snake in terms of the level number

In order to determine the model, we must follow these steps:

Choose your own values (no. of units) for the initial (level 1) dimensions of your snake. State these clearly: length, radius, cross sectional area, volume.

Choose your own growth percentage for the volume.

a well-simplified, precise models are more favorable

Thank you so much, I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

If the volume increases via a percentage $i$ every level $n$ and starts with a volume $v_0$ (when the snake is level $1$), then it gets a simple exponential model:
$$v = v_0(i + 1)^{n-1}$$
Of course, the volume of a cylinder is $v = A\cdot L$:
$$AL = v_0(i + 1)^{n-1}$$
Use your constant $k$ such that $A = L / k$:
$$\frac{L^2}{k} = v_0(i + 1)^{n-1}$$
Of course, solving that for L:
$$L = \sqrt{v_0k}(i + 1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$
Another way of handling this is to find $v$ for any given level, and realize that:
$$L = \sqrt{kv}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes so much sense now :)